# yast network settings: print or log

Tags: networking, command-line, opensuse, static-ip, yast

I'm trying to configure a static ip address on OpenSuSe but don't know how to log or print the network settings to the console with Yast.  How do I print out the yast settings?  I've been reading the [fine manual](https://en.opensuse.org/Portal:YaST), but haven't found a section explaining how to do that yet.